# Splitting string in c# by delimiter

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `"foo|bar|time||||etc|"`

I want to loop through each entry and save them one by one in a ArrayList. The delimiter is '|'.

For example, the ArrayList should contain:

```
"foo"
"bar"
"date"
""
""
""
"etc"
""
```

How do I save each string in an ArrayList?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) your string with `|` and use `ToList` method like;

```
var s = "foo|bar|time||||etc|";
var list = s.Split('|').ToList();
```

[image]

And it's almost 2016. Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. This structure belongs on old days when C# doesn't have [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). `Use List<T>` instead.

Comment: `string.Split` return `string[]`. why `.ToList()`?

Comment: @ASh Since OP try to use `ArrayList` which is and old structure, I want to show him which structure can be used on modern C# language.

Answer (score 1):

use `string.Split` and `ToList`

```
string str = "foo|bar|time||||etc|";
List<string> words = str.Split('|').ToList(); //a lot better than ArrayList
```

Comment: `string.Split` return `string[]`. why `.ToList()`?

Comment: because the OP asks for a list, so I thought he may want to take advantage of the List rather than array.